# Ubuntu 18.04 think C/C++ source code file is plain text

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus, mime-types, file-command

When I try to create a C/C++ source file

```
touch test.cpp
```

Usually it will generate a file which type is C source code file. But today I got a plain text file.
[image]

And I write a simple program in it like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ printf("hello");}
```

Then I use G++ to compile it:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

However, I got a sharedlib file instead of executable file.
[image]

And I can run the sharedlib file and get the correct ouput:

```
./test
hello
```

In the past, I can directly create a C++ source code file and this file type is easy to edit in vscode. But the plain text file is not comfortable for me.

So the two questions really bother me:

1. why my Ubuntu can not recognize C/C++ source code file correctly?
2. why I get a sharedlib file by using default g++ command?

Answer (score 0):

The command `touch test.cpp` creates a plain text file in Ubuntu 18.04 by default as it should. Next try opening test.cpp in Gedit text editor and pasting the following code as you did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ printf("hello");}
```

Save the file. Now look at the right side of the bottom panel in Gedit and you will see that the file type has changed to C++. Right-click test.cpp and select *Properties* and you will see that the Type has changed to *C++ source code (text/x-c++src)*. You should have no problem running test.cpp which now has type *C++ source code (text/x-c++src)* in Visual Studio Code.

If you want to get an executable/x-sharedlib file (which has a lavender diamond-shaped icon with two gears in Ubuntu 18.04) instead of an application/x-sharedlib file, then you need to create a new project for the test.cpp source code in Visual Studio Code before running it.

Comment: Its type becomes c++ source code file. But when I edit it in VSCode, if I delete the 
 `#include <stdio.h>`  , and then I try to rewrite this code, the autocomplete doesn't have reaction. In the past, when I input  `#incl` , the autocomplete will help me to finish `#include`

Comment: That's an unexpected result because whenever you edit a C++ source code file in Visual Studio Code the autocomplete functionality should work properly, especially if you have already saved the C++ file at least once in Visual Studio Code.